# Binary Tree Search not returning the expected value

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

If I have a structure:

```
struct node{
  int key_value;
  node * p_left;
  node * p_right;
};
```

And an add function:

```
node* add(node * p_tree, int key) {
  //--The base case of the recursive function will be placed in here
  //--since binary trees are recursive in nature and linked data structures
  //--are as a whole in terms of space and memory, the recursive function will
  //--suffice for most cases involving binary trees.
  //--In this case, if the given parameter is null, we create the tree
  //--by allocating the necessary memory space
  if (p_tree == NULL) {
    node * pnew_tree = new node;
    pnew_tree->p_left = NULL;
    pnew_tree->p_right = NULL;
    pnew_tree->key_value = key;
    cout << "Added node: " << pnew_tree->key_value << endl;
    return pnew_tree;
  }// end of base case

  //--Depending of the value of the node, we determine if we will add to the left side or the right side of the subtree
  if (key < p_tree->key_value){
    // if it is less than the value, we add to the left
    p_tree->p_left = add(p_tree->p_left, key);
  }
  else{
    p_tree->p_right = add(p_tree->p_right, key);
  }
  return p_tree;
} // end of function
```

As well as a search function:

```
node* search(node *p_tree, int key) {
  //--First:
  if (p_tree != NULL) { 
    if(key == p_tree->key_value){
      cout << "Node found" << endl;
      return p_tree;
    }
    if(key < p_tree->key_value){
      return search(p_tree->p_left, key);
    }
    else{
      return search(p_tree->p_right, key);
    }
  }
    else{
      return NULL;
    }


}//--End of recursive search function
```

Why is it that when I run:

```
 add(myBinaryTree,1);
 cout << "Testing to see if it is there" << endl;
 if (search(myBinaryTree,1) == NULL {
   cout << "Node not found" << endl;
 }
```

The output is "Node not found" instead of "Node found" ?
as far as I know the add function does not return NULL, why is this the case?
I have tried looking into similar questions, but cannot comprehend the code in them enough to come up with my own solution, I am also not well versed in debugging using my IDE(codeblocks) and thus do not know where to go.
(I just need a logical fix since I can not seem to find one in myself)

Comment: Your first step, before posting here, would be to run this in your debugger.

Comment: Why is your `add` function returning a pointer?  I would expect that an `add` or `insert` function adds a node to the list; no return values expected.  Need more code to clarify how the tree is implemented.

Comment: @KevinDTimm that would be wonderful if it were not for the fact that I do not know anything about debugging, If I knew how to I would be glad to implement said solution and would not have asked in here, but I currently do not have the time and need to come up with a quick solution.

Comment: @Alex_adl04: Consider your program the first step in learning a debugger.  If you need a quick solution, use `std::map`; or a external library, as they have already been debugged, saving you precious development time that can be spent learning a debugger.

Comment: To solve this issue you should post the declaration of `myBinaryTree` including all assignments. I wouldn't be surprised if the members of `myBinaryTree` are not initialized properly. @Alex_adl04: You use C++, not C, so I highly recommend to initialize the members of your struct in the constructor. **I highly recommend you to learn how to use a debugger! You can solve such issue normally in less than 20 secondson your own for such code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `add` returns a pointer to the root of the binary tree. Normally this is just the same pointer as the function parameter `p_tree`, since the root of a binary tree never changes.

But in the case of an empty tree (`p_tree == NULL`), than `add` will return a pointer to the newly created tree-root. So you have to update your variable `myBinaryTree`. After executing

```
node* myBinaryTree = NULL;
add(myBinaryTree,1);
```

the variable `myBinaryTree` has still the value `NULL`. You haven't updated it to the root of the tree. The following code works:

```
node* myBinaryTree = NULL;
myBinaryTree = add(myBinaryTree,1);
cout << "Testing to see if it is there" << endl;
if (search(myBinaryTree,1) == NULL) {
    cout << "Node not found" << endl;
}
```

Comment: got it! I greatly appreciate the effort in helping me solve this issue. I was under the assumption that I could call the function and do not have to pass it as an assignment being that it was using pointers, thus thinking that that itself would suffice to work on the node. Easy fix and it works great now, thank you.